pmset scheduled reboot vs. filevault
I want my Mac to be remotely accessible even after rebooting. This is prevented by FileVault and one needs to physically login first after the reboot. One can solve this by the command line fdesetup authrestart.
However, this is only useful for an immediate restart. I want instead the restart pmset scheduled. For instance, I set pmset relative poweron 25000 and then remotely shut down the machine. 25000s later, it restarts but runs back to the FileVault problem. Any workaround besides turning FileVault off?
